# Two versions of rake installed = errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, version, rvm

I've just upgraded to ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.2. I'm trying to create this application:

```
rails new myapp -m https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates/raw/master/rails3-mongoid-omniauth-template.rb -T -O
```

In the end of the installation it gives me the error:

```
The template [https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates/raw/master/rails3-mongoid-omniauth-template.rb] could not be loaded. Error: You have already activated rake 0.9.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2.2. Using bundle exec may solve this.
```

If i do RVM gem list or gem list I get two versions of rake:

```
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.9.2)
```

How do I tell RVM or whatever it is I have to tell, to use ONLY the latest?

Comment: can you uninstall one? Maybe your 1.9.3 doesn't have both installed?

Comment: I don't know... can I? How do I do that?

Comment: Did you try `gem uninstall`? Or follow the error message and use bundle exec?

Comment: I just did: rvm remove rake-0.9.2, but it removed the newest rake version, rake-0.9.2.2! What's going on here?

Comment: `rvm remove` is for removing Ruby interpreters, their source code and related gemsets. `gem uninstall` is for uninstalling gems. It looks to me like you're a bit confused about which commands belong to `ruby` or `gem` and which to `rvm`. (It can get a bit confusing if you primarily meet Ruby only via an environment manager.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be explicit in your `Gemfile` about the version that you want.

`gem "rake", "0.9.2"`

Update your `Gemfile.lock` with:

`$ bundle update`

Remove the version you don't want.

`$ gem uninstall rake -v 0.9.2.2`

You can reverse these numbers depending on which gem you actually want to use.

Comment: Will try that. Gimmi 5 sec. I still wonder how I can remove it from the rvm gem file, so I don't get an error when I actually create the app?

Comment: That seemed to work... Still wondering on the above question though!

Comment: Probably have to dig into `rvm` if you really want to fix this. I think the issue is that the default rake version isn't the latest, which then conflicts with the default Rails setup. It should only affect project creation though, since as soon as you get a Gemfile built you can specify exactly which versions you want.

Comment: I finally seemed to solve it with some help from an awesome coder friend of mine. It was more than 2 rake versions that was wrong in my ruby developer environment. That's for sure! :-P

Comment: @jdl Where exactly in the Gemfile should I put it? I have rake (10.1.0, 0.9.6) installed but can't get rid of the older version.

Comment: @Steven If `gem uninstall rake -v 0.9.6` does not remove that version of the gem, you should gather up as much info as you can (gem env, etc.) and post a separate question about it. Search first though, because I'm sure that I've seen this issue come up before.

Answer (score 2):

You should run it in the context of your bundle.

```
bundle exec rails new myapp -m https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates/raw/master/rails3-mongoid-omniauth-template.rb -T -O
```

Comment: Then it just gives me: Could not locate Gemfile

Comment: bundle can't run yet, since the Gemfile hasn't been created yet

Comment: Oh, I just thought it's present because Rails 3 uses Bundler by default and thus `Gemfile` should be present.